# Live search through table rows mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search, live

i would like to ask is if there is a way that i can get the data from my database on my search bar if i use this? how can i get data from my database? at the same time show it on the result

$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

```
$("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index != 0) {

        $row = $(this);

        var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

        if (id.indexOf(value) != 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    }
});
```

});​

Comment: No, you can't get the data unless you use Ajax.

Comment: I'm not 100% this is correct from the question and code provided, but this link will help get you started with ajax live search: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp